# partmgr.sys causing BSoD - how do I fix it?

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I have had 3 BSoD on Windows 10, fully updated, in past week.  I dont know if I have had any before this.  I changed from SSD to M2 a couple of months ago - only correlation I can think of.  I used Nirsoft BlueScreenView to view the dump files, and they all say partmgr.sys is the cause. Now what?  A copy of the latest info below:

[image]

Comment: You will have to provide the output of WinDbg in order to really understand the cause of the crash.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. I got the WinDbg in SDK.  But running it on the .dmp in incoherent.  How do I produce the Dgb output?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this Microsoft Article.

[oxca bugcheck](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0xca--pnp-detected-fatal-error#:%7E:text=This%20indicates%20that%20the%20Plug,problematic%20Plug%20and%20Play%20driver.)

> The PNP_DETECTED_FATAL_ERROR bug check has a value of 0x000000CA. This
> indicates that the Plug and Play Manager encountered a severe error,
> probably as a result of a problematic Plug and Play driver.
>
> Invalid PDO: An API which requires a PDO has been called with random
> memory, or with an FDO, or with a PDO which hasn't been initialized.
>
> (An uninitialized PDO is one that has not been returned to Plug and
> Play by QueryDeviceRelation or QueryBusRelations.)

In addition to checking Plug and Play (what devices are you adding), is there a replacement for partmgr.sys or the device that is using it.

The error is quite serious, and if you cannot find any cause, you may need to back up your system completely and reinstall Windows 10. Do that via the Microsoft Media Creation Link and Keep Nothing.

Comment: I dont understand. how do I "check plug and play"?  Is partmgr.sys not a windows program?  Do all devices not use it?  how do I find the one that does?   Is there a replacement?  That is part of the question - What do I replace it with.  Can I disable it and see if anything breaks?  It is not in processes or services, but services does have PlugPlay

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/bootmgr-is-missing-message-or-black-screen-with/13ac7440-c003-4b23-8587-1239d67b9982   Partmgr.sys is a Windows driver that is a small software program that allows your computer to communicate with hardware or connected devices

Comment: You may need to back up and reinstall Windows to correct this.

Comment: I have been running windows for years with this driver with no issues.  It is just recently causing issues.  Not sure the reinstall makes the most sense

Comment: Plug and Play and related drivers are built right in. Something has gone wrong with that. So that it why I make the suggestion. In customer work, serious errors like this are best handled with re-install.